# Am trying to exclude from the GET request the parameters that does not contain values

Tags: python, html, django

I have this code in the search.html

```
<h1>Property Search</h1>
    <hr>
    <form method="GET" action="/search/results/?{{ query_params }}" class="form-inline" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; ">
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
            <label for="inputSaleRent" class="mr-2" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Sale/Rent:</label>
            <select id="inputSaleRent" name="sale_rent" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px;">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="sale">For Sale</option>
                <option value="rent">For Rent</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <label for="inputDistrict" class="mr-2" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: bold;">District:</label>
            <select id="inputDistrict" name="district" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px;">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="District 1">District 1</option>
                <option value="District 2">District 2</option>
                <!-- Add more district options -->
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <label for="inputMunicipality" class="mr-2" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Municipality/Community:</label>
            <select id="inputMunicipality" name="municipality" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px;">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="Municipality 1">Municipality 1</option>
                <option value="Municipality 2">Municipality 2</option>
                <!-- Add more municipality options -->
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <label for="inputParish" class="mr-2" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Parish:</label>
            <select id="inputParish" name="parish" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px;">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="Parish 1">Parish 1</option>
                <option value="Parish 2">Parish 2</option>
                <!-- Add more parish options -->
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <label for="inputPropertyType" class="mr-2" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Property Type:</label>
            <select id="inputPropertyType" name="property_type" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px;">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
                <option value="Studio">Studio</option>
                <!-- Add more property type options -->
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <label for="inputMinPrice" class="mr-2" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Min Price:</label>
            <input type="text" name="min_price" class="form-control" id="inputMinPrice" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <label for="inputMaxPrice" class="mr-2" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Max Price:</label>
            <input type="text" name="max_price" class="form-control" id="inputMaxPrice" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px;">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-left: 10px;">Search</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
```

that basically the user inputs in the search bar the values that is interested and by pressing search it retrieves the properties that matches the values, but if it works only if the user apply all the values of the search.

also my vies.py look like this

```
def property_search(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
return render(request, 'search.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        sale_rent = request.POST.get('sale_rent')
        district = request.POST.get('district')
        municipality = request.POST.get('municipality')
        parish = request.POST.get('parish')
        property_type = request.POST.get('property_type')
        min_price = request.POST.get('min_price')
        max_price = request.POST.get('max_price')
    
        query_params = {}
    
        # Set the query parameters based on the provided values
        if sale_rent:
            query_params['sale_rent'] = sale_rent
        if district:
            query_params['district'] = district
        if municipality:
            query_params['municipality'] = municipality
        if parish:
            query_params['parish'] = parish
        if property_type:
            query_params['property_type'] = property_type
        if min_price:
            query_params['min_price'] = min_price
        if max_price:
            query_params['max_price'] = max_price
    
        properties = Property.objects.all()
    
        # Apply filters based on the search criteria
        if sale_rent:
            properties = properties.filter(sale_rent=sale_rent)
        if district:
            properties = properties.filter(district=district)
        if municipality:
            properties = properties.filter(municipality=municipality)
        if parish:
            properties = properties.filter(parish=parish)
        if property_type:
            properties = properties.filter(property_type=property_type)
        if min_price:
            properties = properties.filter(price__gte=min_price)
        if max_price:
            properties = properties.filter(price__lte=max_price)
    
        # Generate the URL query string without empty parameters
        encoded_query_params = urlencode(query_params)
    
        context = {'properties': properties, 'query_params': encoded_query_params}
        return render(request, 'property_search_results.html', context)
    
    return render(request, 'search.html')
```

the get request after i press search looks like this

`GET /search/results/?sale_rent=sale&district=&municipality=&parish=&property_type=&min_price=1000&max_price=1000000000`

The scope is if the user does not apply any values and press search all the properties to be retrieved, also if the user only selects the sale_rent and place sale all the sale properties to be retrieved, this is not the case on what is going on right now

Comment: Your form is doing `method=GET`, but your handler is specifically taking an early exit in that case.  The handler is looking for `POST`.  You either need to change the form or the handler.

Comment: I would also advise to work with a tool like Django-filter, you are here implementing *a lot* of boilerplate code*, which makes it less easy to spot and fix bugs.

Answer (score 0):

> The scope is if the user does not apply any values and press search all the properties to be retrieved, also if the user only selects the sale_rent and place sale all the sale properties to be retrieved, this is not the case on what is going on right now.

The main reason is that you process this with `request.POST`, indeed you check if `request.method == 'POST'`, which will fail anyway.

But you are using too much boilerplate code here. You can work with a simple filter, provided by the [**`django-filter`** package <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/). First we define a filter with:

```
import django_filters


class PropertyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = NumberFilter(field_name='price', lookup_expr='gte')
    max_price = NumberFilter(field_name='price', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = (
            'sale_rent',
            'district',
            'municipality',
            'parish',
            'property_type',
        )
```

Then we can filter in the view with:

```
def property_search(request):
    _filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Property.objects.all())
    encoded_query_params = urlencode(
        {
            k: request.GET[k]
            for k in (
                'sale_rent',
                'district',
                'municipality',
                'parish',
                'property_type',
                'min_price',
                'max_price',
            )
            if k in request.GET
        }
    )

    context = {'properties': _filter.qs, 'query_params': encoded_query_params}
    return render(request, 'property_search_results.html', context)
```

here the filter will thus look if the item is in the `request.GET` dictionary, and if it is, filter the queryset accordingly.